# Is MD5 reliable for encrypting WordPress users passwords

Tags: wordpress, security

Need help with MD5 algorithm that is used to encrypt the WordPress users' passwords in phpMyAdmin. Wikipedia says its unsuitable for use because of security flaws in the algorithm. Does WP still uses it? If not, which algorithm is currently used?

Comment: [General hashing algorithms (eg, MD5, SHA-1/256/512) are not recommended for password storage](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/06/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes.html)

Comment: There is a great answer on hashing of passwords here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108068/what-hashing-algorithm-should-i-use-for-storing-passwords EDIT: It looks like WordPress is indeed using MD5: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password But apparently you can replace this behavior via plugins.

Comment: MD5 is not technically encryption, it's hashing. It is currently considered unsuitable for passwords. It looks like WordPress uses phpass, which (hopefully) uses bcrypt on your system. See http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/wordpress-password-hashes/