# I'm trying to find a hashing algorithm for my website's login system.

Tags: php, security, authentication, hash, salt

Im trying to find a secure salted password hashing algorithm for my website. It is recommended that I get one from a reputable source instead of making one on my own. Where can I find such an algorithm?

Im making my front end with HTML and Javascript and my back-end with PHP.

Comment: what's wrong with http://php.net/password_hash?

Comment: @Ekin, I haven't tried anything so far. This is my first time making such a system. My professor didn't recommend using SHA256 or SHA512 because they're so common.

Comment: @Marc, I heard about password_hash() but I wanted to get the full range of options.

Comment: https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016

Comment: For general information, read the Thomas Pornin's  security.stackexchange.com answer to [How to securely hash passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/39623) - and then, as Marc B and 
Sébastien Vercammen said, use password_hash() and password_verify().  Use a higher work factor!

Answer (score 4):

PHP's [password_hash()](http://php.net/password_hash) supports bcrypt, which is what I recommend. In short, it's a very expensive algorithm that takes a lot of time to compute, hence making it impossible (very slow, so too costly in practice) to bruteforce.

You can find more information with some more links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108068/what-hashing-algorithm-should-i-use-for-storing-passwords).

Comment: Don't forget to increase the work factor!